# Runtime C# Compile All Files in a Folder from Code

Tags: c#, mono, csharpcodeprovider, runtime-compilation

I am successfully doing run-time compilation using the code below. Except that when the number of input *.cs files is large I get the following error.

> System.SystemException: Error running mono.exe: The filename or extension is too long.

I believe this is due to the command line length limit as in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553).

Here is the code

```
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider (
                   new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });

string EngineOutput = Path.GetFileName(dir) + ".dll";

parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.OutputAssembly = EngineOutput;

CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (parameters, engineFiles.ToArray ());
```

Since all source files are in one folder, if there is a way to pass that folder using the -recurse programmatically will be great. Or if there were a method that takes a folder like codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDirectoryRecursive that would have also been great, but to my knowledge that doesn't exist.

I tried the following, but it didn't work. The compiler only picks the fake.cs and not the folder specified by /recurse.

```
parameters.CompilerOptions += " /recurse:" + dir + System.IO.Path.PathSeparator + "*.cs";
results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (parameters, new string[1] { "fake.cs" });
```

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced the PathSeparator with DirectorySeparator, then it works.

```
parameters.CompilerOptions += " /recurse:" + dir + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "*.cs";
```